# update Excel file in datagrid veiw and save to database

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, import

i would like help with updating data into datagridview from an excel import.
I can import the data successfully, and the datagrid is already bound to database table. but i cant seem to find any way of saving this already imported excel sheet to database and then update it with another excel import. I would also like your advice on how i can make the application light weight so that it does not lag with heavy data

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Voluntary_Dtabase
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dbvoluntaryDataSet.iexel' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.


    }
    DataSet result;
    private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter="Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fs);
                    result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                    {
                        ConfigureDataTable = (data) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                        {
                            UseHeaderRow = true
                        }
                    });
                    cbosheet.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                        cbosheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void cbosheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = result.Tables[cbosheet.SelectedIndex];
    }

    private void toolStripButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void tbRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Noted, Thanks @Hearen

Comment: 1. You have to save your data into database like SQL Server by using SqlBulkCopy option for heavy data + performance. 2. Load the saved data into C# application and compare with newly imported data and then update into database using Stored Procedure with TVP (Dataset update - row by row update not bulk one).

Comment: thanks, i will try that out @SelvaTS